# RoR "No Route Matches" on POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

**What i have:**

*Routes:*

```
resources :tests do
  resources :resultsets, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  resources :testresults, :only => [:edit, :update] do
    resources :testnotes, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
  end
end
```

*Submitted form: (No additional variables)*

```
<%= form_for [@session, @testresult, @testnote], :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :line %>
<% end %>
```

`@session` is a Test
`@testresult` is a Testresult
`@testnote = Testnote.new`

*Controller Actions:*

```
def create
  @testresult = Testresult.find(params[:testresult_id])
  @testnote = Testnote.find_or_create_by_line(params[:testnote][:line])
  @connection = Testnoteconnection.find_or_initialize_by_testnote_id_and_testresult_id(@testnote.id, @testresult.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @connection.new_record? and @connection.save
      format.js
    else
      format.js { render :partial => 'error' }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @testresult = Testresult.find(params[:testresult_id])
  @testnote = Testnote.find(params[:id])
  @connection = Testnoteconnection.find_or_initialize_by_testnote_id_and_testresult_id(@testnote.id, @testresult.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @connection.new_record? and @connection.save
      format.js
    else
      format.js { render :partial => 'error' }
    end
  end
end
```

**What is the error:**

Everything, but the response, is working fine. The database is working correctly and the entries are being created as they should. But the browser throws me the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"testnotes", :test_id=>nil, :testresult_id=>#<Testresult id: 13, resultset_id: 4, testobjecttype_id: 114, testtype_id: 1, result: nil, randomed_order: 0, created_at: "2012-11-28 16:22:49", updated_at: "2012-11-28 16:22:49">, :id=>#<Testnote id: 10, line: "asdf", created_at: "2012-12-05 16:06:17", updated_at: "2012-12-05 16:06:17">}
```

**My thoughts:**

Short: I have absolutly no idea!
Obviously the routing is fine, else the server would not even reach the controller action and do those database entries. But what is creating the second routing request? And why isn't the respons being rendered correctly?

**Edit:**
The form is submitting correctly and being routed properly to the `create` action, which is being called correctly aswell. And everything works until `format.js`. Could the problem be in the view?

**Edit2: (View and partial)**

*Create.js*

```
$('#notes_drop').closest('tr').before('<%= j render :partial => "testnotes/testnote", :locals => {:note => @testnote} %>');
```

*testnotes/testnote partial*

```
<tr id='comment_<%= dom_id(note) %>'>
  <td>
    <%= note.line %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to 'delete', test_testresult_testnote_path(@session, @testresult, note), :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you restart the web server after updating the routes?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW yes i did, but as you can see from the actual error this does not seem to be a routing problem. My desired actions are being done, just the respone throws me another route. The actual route is going to `create`, but the error throws me the action `update` and a bunch of senseless variables. So somehow the route goes to something unclear and i think the problem is in the controller (and action `create`)!

Comment: Can you include the view code for the js format?

Comment: @Charles done. Not seeing anything suspicious there...

Comment: See my answer.  You probably need to make sure that `@session` is not `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:  Your view includes the line
`test_testresult_testnote_path(@session, @testresult, note)`

Since `@session` is nil, the Rails router can't figure out how to generate the `test_testresult_testnote_path`.

Original answer below.

My guess is that your view code for format.js includes code that is trying to find a particular route.  Maybe your js view code is trying to render the form partial?

In any case, if you look at

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"testnotes", :test_id=>nil, :testresult_id=>#<Testresult id: 13, resultset_id: 4, testobjecttype_id: 114, testtype_id: 1, result: nil, randomed_order: 0, created_at: "2012-11-28 16:22:49", updated_at: "2012-11-28 16:22:49">, :id=>#<Testnote id: 10, line: "asdf", created_at: "2012-12-05 16:06:17", updated_at: "2012-12-05 16:06:17">}
```

You'll notice that `:test_id =>nil`, which means that you're not passing a Test instance for routing.  Since your `:testnotes` are defined as a nested resource under `:testresults`, which is nested under `:tests`, you will have to pass a non-nil instances of TestResult and Test in order to generate a route correctly.

Are you instantiating the @session variable in a before_filter?  If not, try instantiating @session in your update action, and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Added `@session = Test.find(params[:test_id])` to Create and Update Actions. Works now. Thanks alot for digging into a huge load of code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly speculative answer as I don't have the environment setup here to test in (pun).

My bet would be some Class/Namespace conflict with the keyword `Test`. I know it is a bit of a pain, but did you try changing it to `Testo` or something? You might learn something in the process, your configs look good, and I had this kind of class conflict before, so that's where my recommendation come from

Comment: Test is used for the test directory and probably causes the conflict.

Comment: @ReubenMallaby Wasn't the problem, Charles found the mistake. But you are right, `Test` seems to be a bad choice, i will consider renaming it, though it is quite a bunch of code...